# Okta API: SMS Multi-factor Issue

Tags: api, okta, okta-api, multi-factor-authentication

I'm attempting to use the Okta API in a web application to allow users to activate/deactivate a SMS MFA factor on their accounts.  However, I'm running into an issue as detailed below:

First, on a newly created account:

1. An SMS factor is enrolled via the [Enroll Okta SMS Factor](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/factors.html#enroll-okta-sms-factor) API method.
2. This factor is subsequently activated via the [Acivate SMS Factor](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/factors.html#activate-sms-factor) API
   method.
3. Then we deactivate the factor using the [Reset Factor API](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/factors.html#reset-factor)
   method.

All of this works fine and without errors, however, now when trying to enroll a SMS factor again:

- If using the same phone number: No security code will be sent and SMS
  two-factor auth will be enabled without requiring verification (this
  is okay but unexpected)
- If using a different phone number: Okta returns the following error object:

  ```
  stdClass Object
  (
      [errorCode] => E0000001
      [errorSummary] => Api validation failed: factorEnrollRequest
      [errorLink] => E0000001
      [errorId] => oae3MBJJpGrR6Oj_MkGOxed_g
      [errorCauses] => Array
          (
              [0] => stdClass Object
                  (
                      [errorSummary] => There is an existing verified phone number.
                  )
          )
  )
  ```

How can I resolve this issue?  Am I missing a step where I have to remove a previously verified phone number? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The update method for this endpoint isn't documented but it can be performed.

I do **not** know how to recover the process if you have previously removed SMS and do **not** know the previously registered phone number.

Outside of that scenario, if you are changing a number do the following.

1. Get the full [list of factors](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/factors.html#list-enrolled-factors)
2. Identify the SMS factor to be changed (we need the fid)
3. Using the factor id of the existing SMS and the new phone number

   ```
   POST https://{yourorg}.com/api/v1/users/{:uid}/factors/{:fid}
   {
       "profile":
       {
           "phoneNumber": "+1 555 123 1234"
       }
   }
   ```
4. The response will be the same as that of a [newly enrolled](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/factors.html#enroll-okta-sms-factor) SMS factor
5. [reset/delete](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/factors.html#reset-factor) the existing fid
6. [Activate](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/factors.html#activate-sms-factor) the new factor using

If you run into a situation where the previous factor was reset and you don't know the fid but do know the number you can [enroll](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/factors.html#enroll-okta-sms-factor) the number, retrieve that fid and then begin the sequence described above.

Answer (score 1):

If the user wants to use a different phone number (instead of the existing phone number), then the enroll API call needs to supply the updatePhone query parameter set to true.

The phone number can't be updated for an SMS Factor that is already activated. If you'd like to update the phone number, you need to reset the factor and re-enroll it:

List enrolled Factors and extract the relevant factorId.
Reset the Factor
Then enroll the Factor again. You are able to pass the updatePhone parameter set to true, along with an updated phoneNumber value for as long as the Factor has a status value of PENDING_ACTIVATION.

Request example

```
curl -v -X POST \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: SSWS ${api_token}" \
-d '{
  "factorType": "sms",
  "provider": "OKTA",
  "profile": {
    "phoneNumber": "+1-555-415-1337"
  }
}' "https://${yourOktaDomain}/api/v1/users/${userId}/factors?updatePhone=true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement
I tried the following process:

1.Get the Factors list from the user using `GET FACTORS` --Extract the FactorID.

2.Delete the Existing SMS FACTOR by using `DELETE FACTOR` - FactorId has to be mentioned in the URL

3.Then use the `{{url}}/api/v1/authn/factors?updatePhone=true`

This process helped me in deleting the activated SMS factor and enrolling the SMS as MFA with updated mobile number.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace an existing SMS with a new one and send an OTP to the user:

1. Step 1: https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/factors/#list-enrolled-factors
2. Step 2: https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/factors/#reset-factor
3. Step 3: https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/factors/#request-example-9

If you want to replace an existing SMS with a new one and without sending an OTP to the user:

1. Step 1: https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/factors/#list-enrolled-factors
2. Step 2: https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/factors/#reset-factor
3. Step 3: Similar to Step 3 above, but with ?activate=true. Curl below:

   curl -v -X POST 
   -H "Accept: application/json" 
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
   -H "Authorization: SSWS ${api_token}" 
   -d '{
   "factorType": "sms",
   "provider": "OKTA",
   "profile": {
   "phoneNumber": "+1-555-415-1337"
   }
   }' "https://${yourOktaDomain}/api/v1/users/${userId}/factors?updatePhone=true&activate=true"