# Okta API: SMS Enroll Factor Issue

Tags: okta, okta-api

I'm attempting to use the Okta API in a web application to allow users to activate/deactivate a SMS MFA factor on their accounts. However, I'm running into an issue as detailed below:

First, on a newly created account:

1. An SMS factor is enrolled via the [Enroll Okta SMS Factor API](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/factors.html#enroll-okta-sms-factor) method.
2. This factor is subsequently activated via the [Acivate SMS Factor API](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/factors.html#activate-sms-factor) method.
3. Then we deactivate the factor using the [Reset Factor API](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/factors.html#reset-factor) method.

Now I again want to enroll for SMS factor but this time I am not able to receive SMS and OKTA auto activate my SMS factor.

Here issue is auto-activating sms factor.

How to fix this issue. Any lead will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a question similar to yours and this answer might help solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58975572/10868827

I do not have enough reputation to create a comment for this, sorry!